# How many fields can be used in mysql select query?

Tags: mysql

Can any one please let me know the limitations of MySql Select field counts, I mean how many number of fields that we can use in our Mysql Select query?

> For Example: SELECT field1, field2, field3, ... **field-N** FROM
>   Table1

What can be the maximum value for N?

Comment: Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 2):

## Enough.

---

I didn't find the maximum number of columns in a `SELECT` clause in the MySQL Reference, but I did find the [**maximum number of columns in a table, which is 4096**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html) (or far less, ymmv for InnoDb etc.).

I am sorry that I cannot give a definite answer, but I do imagine three *possible* answers to your question:

- The maximum number of columns in a `SELECT` is **exactly 4096**, since `SELECT` effectively creates a table.
- The maximum number of columns in a `SELECT` is a **multiple of 4096** so that you can select and join multiple tables.
- There is **no limit**.

Either way, I would say the answer is *enough*: I cannot imagine a case where you would need to select more than 4096 columns, and if you do, you will likely run into other problems (timeouts) first.